# Bitcoinj send payment from a wallet

Tags: java, transactions, payment, bitcoin, bitcoinj

I want to make a send payment from my wallet.

```
public static Transaction send(Wallet wallet,String destinationAddress,long satoshis, NetworkParameters parameters)
            throws Exception {
        Address dest = Address.fromBase58(parameters, destinationAddress);
        SendRequest request = SendRequest.to(dest, Coin.valueOf(satoshis));
        Wallet.SendResult result = wallet.sendCoins(request);
        Transaction endTransaction = result.broadcastComplete.get();
        return endTransaction;
    }
```

or tried to make

```
 SendRequest req;
        Transaction transaction = new Transaction(parameters);
        Coin coinToSpend = Coin.valueOf(600);
        //Address addressoSpend = new Address(parameters,"1PSq12YPRBCGwmb2cqqXaGpRrLfotsthPv");
        transaction.addOutput(coinToSpend,Address.fromBase58(parameters,"18MQPpjbB5UUwZBT7DALE6Q55pKCtfPCK3"));
        req = SendRequest.forTx(transaction);
        Wallet.SendResult sendResult = restoredWallet.sendCoins(req);
```

both of them return

```
Exception in thread "main" org.bitcoinj.core.InsufficientMoneyException: Insufficient money,  missing 0.0004729 BTC
```

How to make a proper send payment to another BTC address?

Comment: Seems like the wallet of which you're sending from has a balance lower than the amount you want to spend

Comment: No, I have 2410 satoshi. I think it's enough

Answer (score 1):

The problem actually was with the input and output. In new versions of bitcoinj you should set unput and output ot make transaction. Unfortuanetly, it was not updated on [officail page](https://bitcoinj.github.io/getting-started-java#sending-coins). Here below is the answer for my question:

```
            Coin value = Coin.valueOf(680l);
            Address to = Address.fromBase58(parameters, addressTo);

            Transaction transaction = new Transaction(parameters);
            transaction.addInput(wallet.getUnspents().get(0));// important to add proper input
            transaction.addOutput(value, to);

            SendRequest request = SendRequest.forTx(transaction);
            request.feePerKb = Coin.valueOf(1000);

            Wallet.SendResult sendResult = wallet.sendCoins(peerGroup, request);
```